# How to highlight part of the graph with ggplot's geom_smooth?

Tags: r, ggplot2

What I want to do is highlight a part of a geom_smooth plot. After some searching I found `gghighlight`, but this doesn't work for `geom_smooth`. What R does in `gghighlight` is create a new `geom_smooth` line and highlight that, while I want to highlight the part of the first `geom_smooth`.

Examplecode:

```
Dates <- seq(as.POSIXct("2018-01-01 00:00:00"), as.POSIXct("2021-01-01 00:00:00"), by = "days")

values <- rnorm(length(Dates), 1000, 500)

df <- data.frame(Dates, values)

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data = df, aes(Dates, values))+
  scale_x_datetime(breaks = scales::breaks_width("years"), date_labels = "%Y")+
  geom_smooth()+
  gghighlight::gghighlight((as.POSIXct("2020-03-24 00:00:00") <= Dates) & (Dates <=  as.POSIXct("2020-04-14 00:00:00")))
```

The plot you'll see if you run the code

[image]

As you see in the image the highlighted(blue) part does not follow the overall line at all. How would you highlight on the line?

Answer (score 0):

One option to achieve your desired result would be to manually compute the smoothed line and add the predictions and standard errors to your df. In case of a `loess` curve this could be achieved like so:

```r
library(ggplot2)

Dates <- seq(as.POSIXct("2018-01-01 00:00:00"), as.POSIXct("2021-01-01 00:00:00"), by = "days")

set.seed(123)

values <- rnorm(length(Dates), 1000, 500)

df <- data.frame(Dates, values)

pred <- predict(loess(values ~ as.numeric(Dates), df), se = TRUE)
df$pred <- pred$fit
df$se <- pred$se.fit

ggplot(df, aes(Dates, pred)) +
  geom_line(color = "blue", size = 1) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = pred - 1.96 * se, ymax = pred + 1.96 * se), fill = "grey45", alpha = .2) +
  gghighlight::gghighlight((as.POSIXct("2020-03-24 00:00:00") <= Dates) & (Dates <=  as.POSIXct("2020-04-14 00:00:00")))
```

[image]